# Simulating top, bottom, left and right margins in tkinter pack geometry

Tags: python, tkinter

What should be done to have **left_margin** (*cyan*) and **right_margin** (*magenta*) frames taking all vertical height from **top_margin** to **bottom_margin**?

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

top_margin = tk.Frame(root, height=32, background='red')
left_margin = tk.Frame(root, background='cyan')
sheet_area = tk.Frame(root, background='white')
right_margin = tk.Frame(root, background='magenta')
bottom_margin = tk.Frame(root, height=32, background='blue')

top_margin.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.N)
bottom_margin.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.S)
left_margin.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
right_margin.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think I know what your problem is. You are packing the top and bottom margins before the left and right. without setting any specific size for the margins.

If you change your pack statements to look like this:

```
left_margin.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
right_margin.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
top_margin.pack(side=tk.TOP, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.N)
bottom_margin.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.X, anchor=tk.S)
```

If you want the top and bottom margins to be visible add a width as well. Like so:

```
bottom_margin = tk.Frame(root, width = 10, height=32, background='blue')
top_margin = tk.Frame(root, width = 10, height=32, background='red')
```

Hope this solved your problems :)